How can I debug a slow (software) RAID 10 array?
I have a software RAID 10 array setup using mdadm. There are 8 separate disks. Both read and write speeds are extremely slow, especially writes. Any large (multi-GB) file added to the filesystem is enough to bring the entire system to a crawl. The performance is seemingly worse than single disks.
I'm not sure if a disk is slow/failing or if there is another reason for the slow speeds. How can I debug the issue? If a drive is bad, I'd like to replace it. No failures are reported using smartmontools.
The output of cat /proc/mdstat:
md126 : active raid10 sdg1[2] sdc1[6] sde1[7] sdb1[3] sdi1[4] sdd1[0] sdh1[5] sda1[1]
      7813525504 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 offset-copies [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 1/59 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

The output of vmstat 1 5:
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- -------cpu-------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st gu
 0 10 1717760 4034524 203756 54468964    3   17   893   827 4439    2  6  1 89  3  0  0
 0 10 1717760 4033028 203756 54469392    0    0   344    16 7102 8143  1  1 73 25  0  0
 0  9 1717760 4029424 203756 54470224    0    0  1292    32 6800 7362  0  1 71 28  0  0
 0  9 1717760 4028308 203772 54473960    0    0  3292   380 7583 8866  1  1 74 25  0  0
 1  9 1717760 4027860 203780 54477052    0    0  3092    80 6880 7769  0  1 74 25  0  0


Can you provide the result of command: vmstat 1 5?

@RomeoNinov Output of vmstat 1 5 added to the question.

What I see is 9/10 blocked processes and 25% of the system "load" is waiting.
As we do not know what app run on this server this can be (speculation) a lot of concurrent writes on the same filesystem. Also get in mind some filesystems handle better huge files (XFS for example). For test you can create new filesystem and test then. Other wise consideration can be to use hardware RAID controller. This will offload (from processor) the write operations to disks.

I'm using ext4 as the filesystem and am ~60% done with a single large write (~100 GB) that consists of multiple files of various sizes.

@jnasworld223, maybe intensive read/write of inode blocks may be the reason.
